# Como desabilitar campo e botão em angularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Eu tenho um campo de texto e botão para enviar esse texto.
Está tendo um pequeno *delay*, após eu clicar no botão de enviar até a mensagem ser enviada.
Então, preciso desabilitar o campo de texto e o botão, até que a mensagem seja enviada e apareça na tela, depois habilito eles novamente. Como posso fazer isso usando Angular?

HTML:

```
<label class="item-input-wrapper">
    <input type="text" ng-focus="inputUp()" ng-blur="inputDown()" ng-disabled="!mensagem" ng-model="mensagem.msg" placeholder="Texto" />
</label>
<button class="button button-small" ng-click="enviarMsg(mensagem)">Enviar</button>
```

controller:

```
$scope.enviarMsg = function (mensagem) {
    //console.log(mensagem);
    var dia = moment().format(); //2016-02-16 T 16:05:52-02:00
    var diaP = dia.split('T');
    var dia = diaP[0];

    var horaP = diaP[1];
    var horaP2 = horaP.split(':');
    var hora = horaP2[0]+':'+horaP2[1];

    var enviaMsg = {
        mensagem: mensagem,
        idUsuario: $window.localStorage.getItem('idUsuario'),
        idCep: $window.localStorage.getItem('idCep'),
        nome: $window.localStorage.getItem('nome'),
        dia: dia,
        hora: hora
    }

    $http.post("http://www.vigilantescomunitarios.com/www/php/enviaMsgLogra.php", enviaMsg).success(function (data){
        //console.log(data);
        pegaMsgsLogra();
        $scope.mensagem = {
          msg: ""
        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode criar uma variável booleana pra tratar esse problema. Ex:

```
$scope.disableButton = false;
```

No inicio da função `enviarMsg` você seta a variável como `true`: `$scope.disableButton = true;`.

No final, depois te enviar a mensagem é só atribuir a variável como `false` novamente

Depois é só colocar a diretiva `ng-disabled` no código do botão:

```
 <button class="button button-small" ng-click="onTimeout()" ng-disabled="disableButton">Enviar</button>
```

Exemplo(Fiz um timer de 5 segundos pra simular uma requisição):

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);


myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.disableButton = false;

    $scope.counter = 0;
    $scope.onTimeout = function() {
        //Assim que entrar na função seta como true
        $scope.disableButton = true;
        $scope.counter++;
        mytimeout = $timeout($scope.onTimeout, 1000);
        if ($scope.counter >= 5) {
            $timeout.cancel(mytimeout);
            //Depois de terminar a requisição seta como false
            $scope.disableButton = false;
            $scope.counter = 0;

        }
    }


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   {{counter}}
   <button class="button button-small" ng-click="onTimeout()" ng-disabled="disableButton">Enviar</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Legal Techies! Vou tentar.

Comment: @GustavoSevero tudo bem.

Comment: Ficou show de bola Techies

Comment: Eu só não coloquei o "temporizador".

Comment: @GustavoSevero boa sorte com seus códigos :D