# Como desabilitar botão após envio de mensagem?

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Tenho uma app em Ionic que envia mensagens.
Já me ajudaram, aqui no forum mesmo, a fazer uma maneira que não permita que o usuário possa tocar no botão enviar, sem tem digitado nada, para a mensagem não ir em branco. Blz, funciona legal

```
<button class="button button-clear button-positive" ng-disabled="msgForm.msg.$invalid && disableButton" ng-click="enviarMsg(mensagem)">Enviar</button>
```

controller:

```
$scope.enviarMsg = function (mensagem) {
    $scope.disableButton = true;

    var dia = moment().format(); //2016-02-16 T 16:05:52-02:00
    var diaP = dia.split('T');
    var dia = diaP[0];

    var horaP = diaP[1];
    var horaP2 = horaP.split(':');
    var hora = horaP2[0]+':'+horaP2[1];

    var enviaMsg = {
        mensagem: mensagem,
        idUsuario: $window.localStorage.getItem('idUsuario'),
        idCep: $window.localStorage.getItem('idCep'),
        nome: $window.localStorage.getItem('nome'),
        dia: dia,
        hora: hora
    }
    $http.post("http://www.vigilantescomunitarios.com/www/php/enviaMsgLogra.php", enviaMsg).success(function (data){
        $scope.disableButton = false;
        pegaMsgsLogra();
        $scope.mensagem = {
          msg: ""
        }

    });
}
```

Porém, como as vezes a mensagem demora pra sair, gostaria que o botão fica, também, desabilitado e o campo, também, até que a mensagem seja enviada.
Como eu poderia fazer isso? pois já estou usando ng-disabled no botão.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/115273/como-desabilitar-campo-e-bot%C3%A3o-em-angularjs

Comment: Amigo, esse post que vc colou aqui, eu quem fiz e me ajudou em uma parte da minha dúvida. Agora a dúvida é outra.

Comment: De acordo com o quê vc descreveu parece a mesma coisa.. Melhore um pouco sua pergunta.

Comment: Qual sua sugestão de pergunta? Pois parecem a mesma mas não é kkkk

Comment: `ng-disabled="msgForm.msg.$invalid && condicaoMensagem"`

Comment: Blz! Vou tentar

Comment: Cara, não funcionou... Vou colocar o meu código atual aqui no post

Comment: Posta o código inteiro onde vc faz a requisição

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode tentar dessa forma:

```
//Controller

$scope.disableButton = false;

function myController(){
$scope.disableButton = true;
//Requisição
....
//Após o fim da requisição disableButton volta a ser false
$scope.disableButton = false;
}
```

Html:

```
<input type="text" ng-disabled="disableButton"/>
<button class="button button-clear button-positive" ng-disabled="msgForm.msg.$invalid || disableButton" ng-click="enviarMsg(mensagem)">Enviar</button>
```

Exemplo:
http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/3787/

Comment: Valeu,vou tentar...

Comment: Já tenho essa declaração, lá em cima, no início de todo o controller, junto com a inicialização de outras variáveis, o $scope.disableButton = false;

Comment: Mas tentarei mesmo assim.

Comment: @GustavoSevero Atualizei o código, use || ao invés de &&. Coloquei um exemplo também.

Comment: Valeu Diego.
O que faz esse "ng-disabled="disableButton" " no campo de input/

Comment: Desabilita o campo input quando a mensagem estiver sendo enviada.

Comment: Certo.
Mas engraçado que só depois que eu coloquei o ng-disabled no campo de input ai o botão funcionou tb, ficou desabilitado, enquanto a mensagem não fosse enviada

Answer (score 0):

Faz o seguinte:
Na tag form, insira o seguinte código:

```
 onsubmit="this.enviar.value = 'Enviando...'; this.enviar.disabled = true;"
```

Após, no botão submit, insira o seguinte código:

```
name="enviar" id="enviar-contato"
```

Ele vai procurar o botão com o name, após o submit, ele irá desabilitar, e não via mais poder ser clicado até que o envio seja feito.